# Lecture notes of complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, reference-works

I just want to go through the topics of complex analysis, in order to get an overview of the subject. Does there exists any good lecture notes for complex analysis which covers all the topics quickly? Like Milne's notes in Algebraic number theory. I am currently referring Tao's lecture notes on complex analysis, but at many points he has referred to Wikepedia so everything is not covered there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Donald Sarason's [Complex Function Theory](http://users.auth.gr/siskakis/Sarason-ComplexFunctionTheory.pdf).!

In preface:

These are the notes for a one-semester introductory course in the theory of
functions of a complex variable. The aim of the notes is to help students
of mathematics and related sciences acquire a basic understanding of the
subject, as a preparation for pursuing it at a higher level or for employing
it in other areas. The approach is standard and somewhat old-fashioned.

As these notes are a rather bare-bones introduction to a vast subject, the
student or instructor who uses them may well wish to supplement them with
other references